# Что нужно написать в elif, чтобы при вводе отрицательных чисел и чисел больше 12 выводил "ошибка"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input("Введите номер месяца: "))

if n <= 2 or n == 12 or n > 0:
    print("Зима")
elif n <= 5 : 
    print("Весна")
elif n <= 8 :
    print("Лето")
elif n <= 11 :
    print("Осень")
elif n > 12 or n <= 0:
    print("ОШИБКА")
```

Comment: if n <= 2 or n == 12:  ....... else:
    print("ОШИБКА")

Comment: Здравствуйте. Всё равно при вводе отрицательных чисел выводится "зима"

Comment: if n > 0 and (n <= 2 or n == 12):    Про отрицательные я забыл

Comment: перед `if` добавьте `if n < 1 or n > 12:
    print("ОШИБКА")`, а `if` замените на 
`elif n <= 2 or n == 12:`, также уберите `else`

Answer (score 1):

Вообще вот так:

```
elif (n<0 or n>12):
        print("Ошибка")
```

Но у вас ошибка в том, что условие `if(n<=2 и т.д.)` сработает раньше, чем `elif(n<0 or n>12)`, так как число меньше нуля, будет так же и меньше двух. Вообще у вас абсолютно неверный код, неправильно сформированы условия.

Не буду писать код за вас, но немного объясню чтобы вы подумали. Для зимы это будет `if(n==12 or (n>0 and n<3))`, в n==12 вы проверяете является ли месяц декабрём, во второй части условия вы проверяете находится ли он между январём(так как он первый) и мартом(он третий). Проверяется не равно ли число двенадцати ИЛИ число больше нуля И меньше трёх (например n=1). Весна начинается с третьего месяца по пятый `(n>2 and n<6)`. Думайте

Answer (score 0):

Можно нужное условие для целых чисел сформулировать и таким образом: `not (0 < n < 13)`, "все, что не входит в диапазон от 1 до 12".
Подобные задачи циклического характера удобнее решать через индексирование. Результатом выражения `n % 12 // 3` будут числа от 0 до 3, т.е. индексы в кортеже с названиями сезонов.
Дополнительно рекомендую проверять, число ли введено (последовательность цифр) во избежание ошибки при преобразовании.

```
n = input("Введите номер месяца: ")
if n.isdigit():  # проверка, введена ли последовательность цифр
    n = int(n)
else:
    n = -1
if not (0 < n < 13):
    print("ОШИБКА")  # ошибка выводится, когда введено не (целое) число или число находится вне допустимого диапазона
else:
    print(("Зима", "Весна", "Лето", "Осень")[n % 12 // 3])
```